# column count doesn't match value count at row 1 at codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my controller

```
            $nis = $this->input->post('nis');
            $nisn = $this->input->post('nisn');
            $nama_siswa = $this->input->post('nama_siswa');
            $password_siswa = $this->input->post('password_siswa');
            $pass = md5($password_siswa);
            $data = [
                'nis' => $nis,
                'nisn' => $nisn,
                'nama_siswa' => $nama_siswa,
                'password_siswa' => $pass
            ];
            $insert = $this->M_crud->insert("user", $data);
```

this is column in table user:

```
id_user, 
nis, 
nisn, 
nama_siswa, 
password_siswa, 
id_siswa, 
id_eskul
```

But when I insert in phpmyadmin or in my view it's error

```
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `M_crud->insert()` method

Comment: in your table structure there are `7 columns` and you are inserting in `$data` variable only `4`.

Comment: Probably you need to add to your `$data` variable `id_siswa` and `id_eskul` because they are required but show us what `M_crud->insert()` method does. This might be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: Please never use `md5()`. That thing is no longer "good enough".  I also don't see any server-side validation and that is rather scary.  You need to make sure that anything that is going to be saved to your db is adequately validated and sanitized before even thinking about writing it to the db.  We can only offer guesses as to what exactly is wrong and how to fix it because you haven't provided enough vital details in your question.